# VB.net datacolumn.expression - convert seconds to hh:mm:ss

Tags: vb.net

I have a datatable where a column "Duration(s)" is the time in seconds. I have added an expression column and would like to use it to display the Duration(s) column but in the format hh:mm:ss. The msdn document [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) suggests it is possible as TimeSpan  is a supported function.

The following expression is accepted but generates an error when it tries to calculate

(error is: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.EvaluateException' occurred in System.Data.dll - Additional information: Invalid type name 'TimeSpan.FromSeconds([Duration(s)])').

```
Convert([Duration(s)], 'TimeSpan.FromSeconds([Duration(s)])')
```

Does anyone have a working example of how to use TimeSpan correctly in a DataColumn expression as I've not had any luck finding any online (currently I am creating a new column and looping through each row and creating the hh:mm:ss column that way but it is a bit messy that way). I am thinking my error is a combination of incorrect usage of timespan and fact that Duration(s) is an int32 and the msdn doc suggests TimeSpan in this case will only work from string to string.

I'm using VS2013 and target framework is 4.0.

Comment: can you post more of your code, not just part of one line?

Comment: Hi, that is all the code. I created the new datacolumn in the datatable via DataSet Designer and wrote the line above in the Expression box in properties. As a bit more background the datatable is empty at runtime and is populated when data is entered hence no error until data is added.

Comment: Also don't you need a datatable name preceding the column name? DataTable1.([Duration(s)]?

Comment: Only if you are adding programmatically. In the expression box you can just input "Duration(s) * 10" for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CONVERT function expects a Type as second parameter. You cannot use a methid there. Moreover, to use the CONVERT function of the Expression property of a DataColumn with the TimeSpan type you need to create your expression column with the TimeSpan type.
At this point you could use the CONVERT function. The only thing to remember is that the conversion expects that each unit of the value to convert is expressed as 100 of nanoseconds.

So you could try this approach

```
Dim nsec100 as Long = 10000000
Dim ts = new TimeSpan(nsec100)
Console.WriteLine("Total Seconds from 10000000 100ns = " & ts.TotalSeconds)

Dim dt = new DataTable()
dt.Columns.Add("SEC", Type.GetType("System.Int64"))
dt.Columns.Add("TS", Type.GetType("System.TimeSpan"), 
                     "CONVERT(SEC, System.TimeSpan)")
dt.Rows.Add(nsec100)
Console.WriteLine("TimeSpan:" & dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString())
```

This produces the following output

```
Total Seconds from 10000000 100ns 1
TimeSpan:00:00:01
```

At this point you could change your expression to multiply your seconds value for 10000000

```
dt.Columns.Add("TS", Type.GetType("System.TimeSpan"), 
                     "CONVERT(SEC * 10000000, System.TimeSpan)")
```

Comment: Great, thanks Steve this works perfectly. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds([Duration(s)]).Hours.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c) & ":" & _
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds([Duration(s)]).Minutes.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c) & ":" & _
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds([Duration(s)]).Seconds.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c)
```

Comment: Alas it doesn't work. It says "The expression contains undefined function call TimeSpan.FromSeconds()." It seems to be expecting TimeSpan to be used possibly in conjunction with CONVERT I think but the question is how.